# Use of unresolved identifier countElements

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ios9

```
let newLength = countElements(textField.text) + countElements(string) - range.length;
```

When i'm running my app, it suddenly shows the error of unresolved identifier.

Answer (score 4):

It appears you are attempting to use Swift 1.0 code in a later version of Swift. `countElements` was removed in iOS 8.3 (with Swift 1.2) -- you need to be logged in to see the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS83APIDiffs/modules/Swift.html)

in Swift 2.0, it is now `str.characters.count`